# php file can't find the 'Receiver' Class

Tags: php

I got two php files, one view(content) and one Object(Receiver).

content.php

```
<?php

include '../model/Receiver.php';

$receiver = new Receiver;
```

Receiver.php

```
<?php

    namespace app\model;

    use app\model\Invoice;

    class Receiver{

        public function __construct(){
            $Invoice = new Invoice;
        }

    }
```

Project structure

```
.
├── app

│   ├── model
         └── Receiver.php
│   └── view
         └── content.php
```

After running content.php I get this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Receiver' not found in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\invoiceexpress\app\view\content.php:5

I can't find out why it does this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add namespace to `Receiver` class by `namespace app\model;`. You can do with add namespace when using `new` or do with `use` statement:

```
<?php

include '../model/Receiver.php';

use \app\model\Receiver;

$receiver = new Receiver;
```

or

```
<?php

include '../model/Receiver.php';

$receiver = new \app\model\Receiver;
```